# Nothing is displaying on Post detail page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**postdata.js**

```
export const PostData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        slug: "see-the view",
        title: "See the view",
        content: <> <h1>Hey There </h1> </>
    }
]
```

**[postslug].js**

```
import { PostData } from "../../data/postdata";
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const posts = PostData.filter((p) => p.slug === params.postslug);
  console.log(posts);
  const mainpost = JSON.stringify(posts);
  return {
    props: {
      post: mainpost[0],
    },
  };
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = PostData.map((post) => ({
    params: { postslug: post.slug },
  }));

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  return <>{post.content}</>;
};

export default Post;
```

Postdata.js file is containing array of objects. I am trying to fetch the data of blog article using getStaticProps and getStaticPaths. But nothing is displaying.

Comment: how you are trying to fetch the data of blog article?i mean how you make a call to getStaticProps?

Comment: The code is already mentioned above

Comment: i  can't see any call to getStaticProps

Comment: Can you please try to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There are 2 ways

### Important Note:

> If you want to render out the `content` of your post, you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. And make sure that is **HTML** and not JSX. So make sure to replace `className` with `class` and other props

```
const Post = ({ post }) => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />;
};
```

Now follow the below procedure

### ONE

Just wrap the `content` in your post object in a string then you don't need to follow the hassle of the second way

```js
export const PostData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        slug: "see-the view",
        title: "See the view",
        content: `<> <h1>Hey There </h1> </>`
    }
]
```

### TWO

So right now you are returning a string from `getStaticProps` because you are using `JSON.stringify()` on it. After converting it into a string, convert it back to an object using `JSON.parse()`.

That will be a proper JS Object and can be returned through `getStaticProps`

```js
import { PostData } from "../../data/postdata";

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const posts = PostData.filter((p) => p.slug === params.postslug);
  console.log(posts);
  // Converts it into string and then normal object
  const mainpost = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts));
  return {
    props: {
      post: mainpost[0],
    },
  };
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = PostData.map((post) => ({
    params: { postslug: post.slug },
  }));

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />;
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: I cannot wrap the jsx fragment content  in "". It is generating so many errors in file.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA What exact error do you get in your file when you wrap it in strings? Please let me know

Comment: Or even if that does not work, wrap it in backticks (\`). Check the answer now, I edited it

Comment: When I use backtick. The HTML content is displayed as it is. It is not rendering to show the actual article.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA Yeah so read the **IMPORTANT NOTE** I added in the answer. That will solve the issue

Comment: Now the article is displayed but one problem is there. The global CSS is not applied.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA Did you apply the classes in your `content` and did you add those classes in your global CSS?

Comment: Yaa definitely applied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243546/discussion-between-usman-sabuwala-and-prashant-verma).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is from here `const mainpost = JSON.stringify(posts)`

You try to stringify an object and then you call `mainpost[0]` which is already a string

You also can use `find` instead of `filter` to get a single post that can help you to avoid unexpected index access `[0]`

Seemingly, `content` is JSX, so you need to convert it to a string before sending it to `Post`. And then you can parse that HTML string by

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />
```

The possible fix could be

```
import {PostData} from '../../data/postdata'
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
        const mainpost = PostData.find((p) => p.slug === params.postslug)
        mainpost.content = JSON.stringify(mainpost.content)
        return {
          props: {
            post : mainpost
          }
        }
      }
      export async function getStaticPaths() {
        const paths = PostData.map(post => ({
            params : {postslug : post.slug}  
        }))
    
        return {paths, fallback : false}
        
      }
    
      
    const Post = ({ post }) => {
       return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />;
     };
    
    export default Post;
```

Comment: Error: Error serializing `.post.content.$$typeof` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/blog/[postslug]".
Reason: `symbol` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA See the issue is that your object contains some stuff that cannot be directly returned from the `getStaticProps`. So you need to do this: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainpost))`

This will first convert your object into a string and then convert it into proper javascript object and it will work

Comment: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA Here, in your jsx, do you want to just show the HTML directly or you want to render the HTML to the website???

Comment: I want to render it

Comment: What is the value of `mainpost` in `console.log`, could you tell us? @PRASHANTVERMA

Comment: content: {
    '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
    type: Symbol(react.fragment),
    key: null,
    ref: null,
    props: { children: [Object] },
    _owner: null,
    _store: {}
  }

Comment: @NickVu The problem is that he has to wrap it into strings and then use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render the content

Comment: Yuppp, I just checked the JSON data too, @UsmanSabuwala. Seemingly, he is struggling to render it instead of sending data around

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the below:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const posts = PostData.filter((p) => p.slug === params.postslug)
    console.log(posts)
    const mainpost = posts[0];
    return {
      props: {
        post : mainpost
      }
    }
  }
```

Also, change this in file `PostData`:

```
export const PostData = [
{
    id: 1,
    slug: "see-the view",
    title: "See the view",
    content: “Hey There“,
}
```

]

And also change the `Post` page:

```
const Post = ({post}) => {

    return (
        <>

            <h1>{post.content}</h1>
        </>

    )
}
```

I suggest you have a seperate value for `title` and `content` and then wrap the title with `h1` tag and content with `p` tag.

Comment: Error: Error serializing .post.content.$$typeof returned from getStaticProps in "/blog/[postslug]". Reason: symbol cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.

Comment: Can you please share `PostData` file?

Comment: It is already there above.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA Try the above now.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA See the issue is that your object contains some stuff that cannot be directly returned from the `getStaticProps`. So you need to do this: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainpost))`

This will first convert your object into a string and then convert it into proper javascript object and it will work

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA did you check my edit?

Comment: Listen there are many HTML elements in the content. I just add one to shorten it.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA i see, then you can use Usman's solution